# Using Events for TextBox, Label, Button Control inside Design Surface

Tags: c#, winforms, gui-designer, design-surface

Can anyone help me answering to my question that how can we implement the click events for dynamically generated component inside Designer.

I had referred [The DesignSurface (Extended) Class is Back, Together with a DesignSurfaceManager (Extended) Class and a Form Designer Demo!](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60175/The-DesignSurface-Extended-Class-is-Back-Together)[^] website

I have use below snippet inside

```
class MenuCommandServiceExt:IMenuCommandService
```

class but didn't got any success.

```
if ((string)menuItem.Tag == "Label")
                {
                  var lbl1 = (Label)surface.CreateControl(typeof(Label),
                   new Size(300, 20), new Point(10, 80));

                  this.lbl1.Text = "Hello World by DesignSurfaceExt";
                  this.lbl1.Click += new EventHandler(btnclick_Click);
                  this.lbl1.MouseDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.lbl_MouseDoubleClick);   
                }
```

I also tried to achieve it through creating a user control for Label with all the events defined inside the label and creating it through above code snippet but it also didn't worked. Below is the logic I used for user control.

```
if ((string)menuItem.Tag == "Label")
                {
                  var lbl1 = (MyLabel)surface.CreateControl(typeof(MyLabel),
                   new Size(300, 20), new Point(10, 80)); 
                }
```

User Control

```
public class MyLabel : Label
    { 
     public MyLabel()
        {

            this.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(MyLabel_Click);
        }

 void MyLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Clicked");
        }
.........
.....
...
}
```

Also, I want to save/view my custom form which I built inside the Powerful DesignSurface Designer. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score -1):

You just cast an UserControl to type MyLabel:

```
var lbl1 = (MyLabel)surface.CreateControl(typeof(MyLabel), new Size(300, 20), new Point(10, 80));
```

So, it doesn't create an object by constructor.
You should create an object by constructor then add to your "surface" object.

```
MyLabel label1 = new MyLabel();
label1.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(MyLabel_Click);
surface.Controls.Add(label1);
}

void MyLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
MessageBox.Show("Clicked");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No I have tried this solution but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: Guys anyone looked into this. I eagerly require this code as I am in middle of my last semester project. Please help me. Appreciate your coordination.